# Not able to put Debug Point

Tags: eclipse

I am not able to put Debug Point. Attached is Image, have a look at it.

I dont know what is the Mistake.

[image]

**WHAT I HAVE TRIED:**

1) Restart of Eclipse

2) It comes in all the Projects

3) Cleaning the Projects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

click on run menu uncheck skip all breakpoints